# Jenkins (running in Kubernetes) can't resolve Git repository

Tags: git, jenkins, kubernetes, dns

I have an instance of Jenkins running in a pod in Kubernetes. I'm trying to let it connect to a local network git repository server, but I'm getting the error:

```
stdout: 
stderr: ssh: Could not resolve hostname {hostname}: Temporary failure in name resolution 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I added a private key to Jenkins because I thought that authentication was the problem, but that didn't help. I also tried getting a shell into the Jenkins pod and I pinged the {hostname} but then I get the same error `Temporary failure in name resolution`.
If I enter the IP address directly, the ping does work. But when I enter that IP address in Jenkins instead of the {hostname}, then I get a `Connection timed out` error..

I'm surely missing something, but I don't know what.
When I first connected to the repo (from a local machine) I had to accept a server key first, otherwise the connection failed too. Could this be the problem, maybe?

Comment: is your kubernetes in the same network where your git is?

Comment: @YashJagdale Yes, I believe it is (since I can ping the IP directly).

Comment: @YashJagdale Actually, no. They are not on the same network. Kubernetes is running inside a VM, and the reason that I can ping the IP is that a network adapter is using the specific range. I'll have to ask the network admin..